# Git permission error but didn't start new account

Tags: git, permissions

Whenever I try to upload a file to git, I get an error like this.

```
    remote: Permission to DennisMarkham/trainTime.git denied to DennisMarkham.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/DennisMarkham/trainTime.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Other people who get this error have started new accounts.  I have not.  I've been using git for four years, using the same account.  This has not always happened.  Before git started requiring access token instead of passwords, I was fine.  IIRC, though I'm not sure, I think I was able to upload sometime after this.  Now, however, I always get this error.  I didn't start a new git account, so what's the deal?

Comment: Do you have 2FA enabled on your account? You can't use `https` if you have 2FA enabled (on github).

Comment: It's not enabled

Comment: Did you create a token, and are you using that token? What permissions did you give that token? GitHub will happily let you create a token that you can't actually use, so watch out for that.